# css, make distance between row

Tags: html, css

i have a css problem

this is my html code

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="./images/hmm_binggung.png" height="70%"/><a class="pilih_size">Pilih Size</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="list_size">
<span class="inactive" title="Out of Stock">36</span>
<span class="inactive" title="Out of Stock">37</span>
<span class="inactive" title="Out of Stock">38</span>
<span class="inactive" title="Out of Stock">39</span>
<span class="inactive" title="Out of Stock">40</span>
<span class="inactive" title="Out of Stock">41</span>
<a class="list_size" title="42">42</a>
<a class="list_size" title="43">43</s>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="clear">
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="./images/hmm_binggung.png" height="70%"/><a class="pilih_size">Pilih Warna</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="list_warna">
<span class="inactive" title="Out of Stock">Aqua</span>
<a class="list_size" title="Black">Black</a>
<a class="list_size" title="Blue">Blue</a>
<a class="list_size" title="Black">Green</a>
<a class="list_size" title="Blue">Brown</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this my css code :

```
a.pilih_size{
    font-family: Book Antiqua;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
a.list_size{
    font-family: Book Antiqua;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    border: 1px gray solid;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color:#a8e9ff;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#d7d7d7);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d7d7d7 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d7d7d7 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d7d7d7 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d7d7d7 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d7d7d7 100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#d7d7d7));
    margin-top: 50px;
}
a.list_size:hover{
    color: Gray;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#d7d7d7, endColorstr=#ffffff);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#d7d7d7), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
    margin-top: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span.inactive{
    font-family: Book Antiqua;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    border: 1px gray solid;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    color: white;
}
a.this_is{
    font-family: Book Antiqua;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    border: 1px gray solid;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #9adc38;
    color: #525c56;
}
```

and this the output

[image]

i want to make a distace between row of size and color
and after search at so and google i found the answer isi using inline block

i add this css

```
a,span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but the output have make distance to big... how can i make a distance

[image]

if we see above picture

at size kategory no any distance between size list (first row) and text (pilih size) that because all of the list is using `<span>` tag
and at color kategory the distance is big between color list (first row) and text (pilih warna) that because just one of color using `<span>` tag and else is using `<a>` tag

how i make a distance row is same as a distance between size(see below picture??

[image]

can someone help me?? thanks

Comment: Try to mention line-height:auto and alter paddings

Comment: padding to td `#list_warna #list_size{padding-bottom:30px;}` ? or `.clear td{height:30px;}`

Comment: @bansi : padding in td just make distance at lastrow, because it automaticly make new row because space of td is full

Comment: @Sidarthan : thanks that work... i using line-height

Comment: Your margin is too big "margin-top: 50px;" make it smaller like 15px, you have that padding inside both list_size and hover